# how to solve this error, non static method cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, methods, non-static

this is the code

```
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
   String reg_url = "http://10.0.2.2/";
    String method = params [0];
    if (method.equals("register") ){
        String first_name = params [1];
        String last_name = params [2];
        String address = params [3];
        String email = params [4];
        String password = params [5];

        try {
            URL url = new URL(reg_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            HttpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            HttpURLConnection.setDoOutput(True);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    return null;
}
```

and i am getting the error on these two lines

```
HttpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            HttpURLConnection.setDoOutput(True);
```

on the set.RequestMethod("POST") and "setDoOutput(true); error says non static method cannot be referenced from a static context. 
it must be silly mistake but i just can't figure it out so can anybody help me with this please?

Comment: thank you all three members who helped me with my problem. you're the best

Comment: In the future please search for similar questions. This one is asked at least 5 to 10 times a week, and I don't think that the site will benefit from the addition of yet one more. For example: [simple search on error message](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+non+static+method+cannot+be+referenced+from+a+static).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the instance you obtained in the call to `openConnection` :

```
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
```

Note that Java is case sensitive. `HttpURLConnection` is the class name. `httpURLConnection` is a variable referring to an instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
HttpURLConnection.setDoOutput(True);
```

you are accessing non static methods with static method syntax

use the reference `httpURLConnection` too access the methods

```
httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to invoke setRequestMethod and setDoOutput methods on the URLConnection instance.

```
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
   String reg_url = "http://10.0.2.2/";
    String method = params [0];
    if (method.equals("register") ){
        String first_name = params [1];
        String last_name = params [2];
        String address = params [3];
        String email = params [4];
        String password = params [5];

        try {
            URL url = new URL(reg_url);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setDoOutput(True);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    return null;
}
```